# Laravel 5.0 to 5.1 upgrade missing files

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I updated my Laravel 5.0 app to 5.1 following the docs, and it works, but then I began to notice that some things are missing.

For example the database/factories/ is not there and it makes me wonder what other things from outside the vendor folder don't get added/removed or updated.

There is nothing in the docs about factories for the update...

Is there a better way? Feels like I am going to have to create a new 5.1 project and merge the files over.

Comment: Nothing is touched outside `vendor` when upgrading. It is a complete manual procedure.

Comment: So it seems, so... what else needs to be copied over? just go through file by file / folder by folder to compare...

Comment: In my case, following the upgrade procedure, all I had to do was `composer update`, create the `bootstrap/cache` dir and update `lists()` to `lists()->all()`.

Comment: @user2094178 Right. And in your database folder do you have a factories folder?

Comment: No. If you upgrade, the changes to `laravel/laravel` will not be reflected, only `laravel/framework` in the vendor will change. I have a project that started in 4.2, now it is at 5.1.